# Aptana / Eclipse studio won't open

Tags: eclipse, aptana

When I open Aptana Studio 3, I get a popup indicating an error has occurred - see the log file:
The log file says:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 4 2016-06-03 08:20:50.414
!MESSAGE Could not read version file

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 4 2016-06-03 08:20:50.415
!MESSAGE An unexpected network error occurred
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: An unexpected network error occurred
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.readWorkspaceVersion(IDEApplication.java:419)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.checkValidWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:366)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:347)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:254)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

I appreciate your help since I cannot get Aptana to startup.

Comment: what java version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had moved the default project folder and it couldn't find it. I was able to get it working by changing the following line in the configuration/config.ini file in the installation:

> osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Aptana 3 Workspace